# "new file" vs. "added by them" when rebasing in Git

Tags: git

```
Changes to be committed:

new file: <name of file>

Unmerged paths:

added by them: <name of file>
```

The two seems identical in that they are both **new files** not present in the other branch I am rebasing on top of. Is there a difference between `new file:` and `added by them:`

Answer (score 3):

When you are rebasing, "them" and "us", "theirs" and "ours" are reversed in an unexpected way: "they", "theirs", "them" refers to the commits that are being rebased.

In this case,

- `new file` means that `<name of file>` exists on the branch that your are rebasing onto, because it was created there independently,
- and `added by them` means that `<name of file>` was also created in a commit that is rebased.

Since there is a conflict, it means that the file `<name of file>` was created with different content on the two branches.

Comment: "them" and "us", "theirs" and "ours" are ALWAYS reversed in unexpected way. It is a thoroughly broken and evil misfeature of git. It is not humanly possible to remember which is which in which context. It's like "credit" and "debet" in accounting: it initially made sense, but then the entirety of accounting random-walked away from that sense as it developed.